# Interfacing Digibee: System.AccessViolation exception?

Tags: visual-c++, exception, runtime-error

I'm pretty new to Visual C++...the project that I'm currently working on is to create a log of inputs accepted from the Digibee using VC++.

Info about the Digibee: http://www.pc-control.co.uk/digibee_info.htm The manual has the essential code for loading the DLL, calling the functions, etc.

Code seems to be working fine (with some modifications) for a few functions....the problems are:

1. Init()-doesn't accept any parameters but when I code it, I have to pass a parameter for it to work; I pass 0
2. ReadAnalogueInputs()-should accept 4 parameters but when I pass 4, it says too many arguments. Works fine when I pass one..builds successfully but then gives the System.AccessViolation exception.

Please help me!

```
    // Header file for use with dgb.dll

     typedef bool   (*Type_InitDgb)();                              
     typedef bool   (*Type_ReadInputs)(int *inputs);
     typedef bool   (*Type_SetOutputs)(int outputs);
     typedef bool   (*Type_ReadAnalogueInputs)(int *aip1, int *aip2, int *aip3, int *aip4);
     typedef bool   (*Type_SetSensitivity)(int sensitivity);
```

//source file

```
    private: System::Void btn_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    HINSTANCE DgbHandle = LoadLibrary(TEXT("dgb.dll"));
             if (DgbHandle==NULL)
                btn->Text="Error";
             else
             {
             btn->Text="Initialized";
             this->progressBar1->Value=100;
             }

             textBox1->Text="Obtaining pointers\n";
                             TypeInitDgb InitDgb;
             TypeSetOutputs SetOutputs;
             TypeReadInputs ReadInputs;
             TypeReadAnalogueInputs ReadAnalogueInputs;
             TypeSetSensitivity SetSensitivity;
             InitDgb =                   (TypeInitDgb)GetProcAddress(HMODULE(DgbHandle),"InitDgb");
             SetOutputs = (TypeSetOutputs)GetProcAddress(HMODULE(DgbHandle),"SetOutputs");
             ReadInputs = (TypeReadInputs)GetProcAddress(HMODULE(DgbHandle),"ReadInputs");
             ReadAnalogueInputs = (TypeReadAnalogueInputs)GetProcAddress(HMODULE(DgbHandle),"ReadAnalogueInputs");
             SetSensitivity = (TypeSetSensitivity)GetProcAddress(HMODULE(DgbHandle),"SetSensitivity");
             this->progressBar2->Value=100;
             textBox1->Text="Pointers obtained";

             status=InitDgb(0);

             if(status==1)
             {
                 textBox1->Text="Digibee initialized";
                 this->progressBar3->Value=100;
                 SetOutputs(LPCTSTR(0x0001));
                 //SetOutputs(LPCSTR(15));
             }
                             int a1,a2,a3,a4;


             ReadAnalogueInputs(LPCTSTR(&a1));
```

}

Comment: Got the problem. Contradiction in function definition in header file and source file.